# SQL query to summarize by groups of data based on condition

Tags: sql-server, distinct, grouping

My data is structured as given below :

```
Call_Num    Country     Item_Num     Date
  XXX1        GG          1         26-Dec
  XXX1        GG          2          
  YYY1        FF          1         2-Jan
  ZZZ1        HH          1         
  ZZZ1        HH          2              
  YYY1        II          1         3-Jan
  YYY1        II          2         3-Jan
```

My aim is to get a summary table with DISTINCT count of Call_Num as given below:

```
Country    Calls_with_date      Calls_with_partial_date   Calls_with_no_date
 GG               0                         1                      0
 FF               1                         0                      0
 HH               0                         0                      1
 II               1                         0                      0
```

How can this be done in SQL Server using queries. I can get it for all instances of the date field not having a date simple enough. But to get this grouping also into the equation is proving a bit tough for me.

Assumptions:

a) There will be more than 1 call-num per country. For sake of simplicity I mentioned a simple example.

b) I know that when summarizing into a new table as given above we may need to use a query per column. So the answer to the above may be three queries with a similar logic in them.

c) By no date, I mean that all occurrences of the call_num do not have a date assigned. By partial, I mean that one or more may have a date assigned.

d) I count only one call in the summary even though there are multiple in the table as each call can have multiple items and each item can have a date. I am concerned with the overall call_num, hence the split in the summary.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Why country GG and HH only have one date on the result when you data have two rows?

Comment: It is not totally clear what you are trying to do here but some aggregation and counting should be able to solve this fairly easily. For example, why does II have calls_with_date = 1, there are two rows with a date? Help us understand the rules and we can find a solution.

Comment: Hello Juan and Sean. Your concerns are very valid and my apologies for not making it more clear. I want to measure it by distinct call_num only. Each call can have multiple parts and each part can have a different date. I am not concerned about the date being same for both parts. My concern is whether all items for the same call_num have a date. If so, it is counted as 1 call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudo-code for how I would do it:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(
   CASE 
    WHEN Date IS NOT NULL AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE {SameCountry, SameCallNum} AND Date IS NULL OR (Date IS NOT NULL AND {Item_Num is lower than this one}))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
   END
  ) AS Calls_with_date
, SUM(
   CASE 
    WHEN Date IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE {SameCountry, SameCallNum} AND Date IS NULL)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * MyTable WHERE {SameCountry, SameCallNum} AND Date IS NOT NULL AND {Item_Num is lower than this one})
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
   END
  ) AS Calls_with_partial_date
, SUM(
   CASE 
    WHEN Date IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE {SameCountry, SameCallNum} AND Date IS NOT NULL OR (Date IS NULL AND {Item_Num is lower than this one}))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
   END
  ) AS Calls_with_no_date
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Country
```